# How to enable custom string in Django.po for Localization?

Tags: python, django, localization

1. I use this code to create a zh-CN:

   ```
   django-admin.py makemessages -l zh-CN
   ```
2. I add some string to Django.po:

   ```
   msgid "zjm1126"
   msgstr "哈哈哈!!!"
   ```
3. And then compile it:

   ```
   django-admin.py compilemessages
   ```

But I don't find it become chinese words.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `django-admin.py makemessages -l zh_CN`

not user `django-admin.py makemessages -l zh-CN`

`zh_CN`  is different from `zh-CN`

Answer (score 0):

You need to also take two more steps:

1. Mark the string "zjm1126" for translation in your template, for example with `{% trans "zjm1126" %}`.
2. Activate Chinese as the current language.  This is often done for you by Django, but you can do it explicitly if you need to.

Comment: can you look the demo.rar and change it for me , that is a simple code.